# how to test correct render output from SWITCH in React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am new to testing and can not figure out how to test for the correct return output of the Switch statement using Jest. Here is the Switch statement:

```
const Modal = ({isVisible, handleClose, noteID, modalType}) => {
    switch(modalType) {
        case 'update':
            return <UpdateModal isVisible={isVisible} handleClose={handleClose} noteID={noteID}/>;
        case 'delete':
            return <DeleteModal isVisible={isVisible} handleClose={handleClose} noteID={noteID}/>;
        case 'addnote':
            return <AddModal isVisible={isVisible} handleClose={handleClose}/>;
        case 'info':
            return <InfoModal isVisible={isVisible} handleClose={handleClose}/>;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

export default Modal;
```

How should I write the test to test the right output based on the modalType?

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add `data-testid` (or something identifiable) on each of your Update / Delete / Add / Info modals.

And you can test to render your modal with different `modalType` and test if the `data-testid` is correctly displayed.

Comment: And how do I target or set the modalType in the test? What I  am trying is this:
```
describe('switching modals', () => {
    it('sets the right modal', () => {
        const {queryByTitle} = render(<Modal modalType='addnote'/>)
        const addnote = queryByTitle('addnote');
        expect(addnote).toBeVisible();
    })
})
```
but this does not work

Comment: Here is a quicke exemple : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-poitras-ylb7o?file=/src/test.js
You juste need to replace add the data-testid on your custom component.

Comment: Thank You for detailed example. Somehow I am getting an error that the element by given data-testid can not be found. I am importing the Modal component but get ``Unable to find an element with the title: delete``

Comment: I know why it fails the test. It is always rendering the same Modal component, only with different text and buttons inside based on the ModalType prop. The Modal element itself does not have the data-testid's, I am attaching them only to the element that will ultimately render the same Modal if it makes sense. I can see different names of button or text in the errors (when displaying the element where it can not find the data-testid) so I can probably target them instead.

Comment: It works now when I target the different button names in the Modal renders...Thanks